# Regular expression - PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N, \P,

Tags: regex, pcre

I need to use the following regular expression to validate some Asian characters

```
 $regexp = "/^[\-'\u2e80-\u9fff\sa-zA-Z.]+$/"; // with warning

 $regexp = "/^[\-'\sa-zA-Z.]+$/";   // without warning
```

preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N, \P, \p, \U, \u, or \X.

Do you know how to change the regular expression pattern so that I can validate the Asian characters from `\u2e80-\u9fff`

I am using the latest XAMPP

```
Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.1 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
```

Comment: See [regular-expressions.info/unicode](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category). Supports `\p{L}`, etc. and is complete... Assertion "PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N, \P" **is near false**.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

PCRE does not support the `\uXXXX` syntax. Use `\x{XXXX}` instead. See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

Your `\u2e80-\u9fff` range is also equivalent to

`\p{InCJK_Radicals_Supplement}\p{InKangxi_Radicals}\p{InIdeographic_Description_Characters}\p{InCJK_Symbols_and_Punctuation}\p{InHiragana}\p{InKatakana}\p{InBopomofo}\p{InHangul_Compatibility_Jamo}\p{InKanbun}\p{InBopomofo_Extended}\p{InKatakana_Phonetic_Extensions}\p{InEnclosed_CJK_Letters_and_Months}\p{InCJK_Compatibility}\p{InCJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_A}\p{InYijing_Hexagram_Symbols}\p{InCJK_Unified_Ideographs}`

Don't forget to add the `u` modifier (`/regex here/u`) if you're dealing with UTF-8. If you're dealing with another multi-byte encoding, you must first [convert](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding) it to UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

```
'/^[<\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}>]+$/u'；
```

Try this one. The regular expression you posted above is not supported by PHP，but Javascript does support that expression.