# regular expression not working properly in PHP

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php - regular expression - PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N, \P,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538293/php-regular-expression-pcre-does-not-support-l-l-n-p)

i have a function

```
public function valid_city_state($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);

    if(!$data)
    {
        return TRUE;            
    }

    $valid = preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F\s\/\-\)\(\`\.\"\']+$/",trim($data));

    if(!$valid)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('valid_city_state', 'Please enter a valid %s.');
        return FALSE;           
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }       
}
```

it has regular expression

```
$valid = preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F\s\/\-\)\(\`\.\"\']+$/",trim($data));
```

when executing it , it gives the following error

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u at offset 9

Filename: home/auth.php

Line Number: 1632
```

looked at some examples but could not get what is needed

[php - regular expression - PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N, \P,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538293/php-regular-expression-pcre-does-not-support-l-l-n-p)

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?748713-Preg-match-with-php-PCRE-error

please help . thanks in advance .

**UPDATE**

this regular expresson works fine in javascript

Comment: Did you try anything in the first link which said "PCRE does not support the \uXXXX syntax. Use \x{XXXX} instead. See [ http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#codepoint ]"?

Comment: yes i used \u{0080}-\u{024F} insted of \u0080-\u024F but not working

Comment: use **\x{}** not \u{} ... \u#### is supported in javascript not pcre which is why it works there, use the \x{####}

Comment: $str = "عربية";
if(preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ \,\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]+/u", $str))echo "invalid";
else echo "valid";

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$valid = preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\x{0080}-\x{024F}\s\/\-\)\(\`\.\"\']+$/u",trim($data));
```

Switch the `u`s for `x`s and wrap the hex in braces like `{0080}`, also add a trailing `u` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `/^[a-zA-Z\x{0080}-\x{024F}\s\/\-\)\(\`.\"\']+$/` as PCRE does not support \u.
THere is an alternative synthaxe with \p{XXXX} or so

Answer (score 1):

When you use double-quote, aware about [escape sequence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). In your code.

```
$valid = preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F\s\/\-\)\(\`\.\"\']+$/",trim($data));
```

And It will be a bit more confuse when it have both escape sequence for PHP, and escape sequence for PCRE pattern. Let's see,

The last $ is invalid. You have to use '\$'. (When escape, it will be $).

If you want to include 'dot' you have to use `\\\.` (after paste as string, it will be `\.` for PCRE, PCRE will escape again to be 'dot' character. Otherwise if only `.` in PCRE will mean any character.

preg_match function will make you confuse, better to use qoute instead of double-qoute. So, inside the patterns you can worries just only [escape sequence for quote](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single).