# PHP preg_replace return Compilation failed: PCRE does not support

Tags: php

I'm trying to use  `preg_replace` with `[^\\u0000-\\uFFFF]`
and I keep getting

```
Compilation failed: PCRE does not support
```

What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php - regular expression - PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N, \P,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538293/php-regular-expression-pcre-does-not-support-l-l-n-p)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PCRE does not support the `\uXXXX` syntax. Use `\x{XXXX}` instead. For more detail [Regular Expression Unicode](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Also You must double escape the backslash inside quotes ( or triple) to obtain a literal backslash: Example below:

```
'/\\\u([\d\w]{4})/'

"/\\\\u([\d\w]{4})/"
```

In your case regex should be `[^\\\u0000-\\\uFFFF]`

Example:

```
$regex = '[^\\\u0000-\\\uFFFF]';

$text = 'some text';

$a = preg_match($regex, $text, $b);

//var_dump($a);
var_dump($b);
var_dump(preg_last_error());
```

Above example will not produce any warning and error

Answer (score 1):

PCRE does not support the `\uXXXX` syntax. Use `\x{XXXX}` instead. See: [php - regular expression - PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N, \P,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538293/php-regular-expression-pcre-does-not-support-l-l-n-p)

Comment: So it should be [^\\x{0000}-\\x{FFFF}] ?