# Enable Arabic and English letter ( regex - PHP )

Tags: php, regex

I want to allow Arabic & English letter, and space

I try this regex, it's works perfectly on javascript validation

```
/^[a-zA-Zu0621-\u064A\s]*$/
```

but when I make it in php verification like

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Zu0621-\u064A\s]*$/',$name)
```

return this error

> preg_match(): Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l,
>   \N{name}, \U, or \u

any solution ?

Comment: You can't just switch regexs across languages. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538293/php-regular-expression-pcre-does-not-support-l-l-n-p

Comment: You were missing a backslash in your regex `/^[a-zA-Z\u0621-\u064A\s]*$/`. Fyi, JS supports `\uDDDD` notation, PCRE (php) supports `\x{DDDDDD}` notation. It's just hex. Btw, PCRE supports _property_ classes so could do it like `^(?:[a-zA-Z]|\p{Block=Arabic}(?<=\p{L}))*$` if PCRE supports the _block_ keyword. If not, then you could just do it like `^[a-zA-Z\x{620}-\x{64A}\x{66E}-\x{66F}\x{671}-\x{6D3}\x{6D5}\x{6E5}-\x{6E6}\x{6EE}-\x{6EF}\x{6FA}-\x{6FC}\x{6FF}]*$`